# MySQL Utilities seems outdated?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/ has MySQL Utilities 1.4.4 for Mac OS X 10.7.  Is this still updated and recommended to use along with MySQL Workbench? I'm at the latest MySQL Workbench 6.1 CE on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that (1.4.4) is the latest version of the utilities as of 2014-08-20 (although the [version 1.5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-utilities-1.5.1-osx10.7.dmg) is probably going to be released very soon). Since approximately when MySQL 5.6 was released, the MySQL utilities have had an independent download from MySQL workbench (so they can be easily installed on text-only servers) and they have its own numbering schema.

The MySQL Utilities 1.5 will probably be released at the same time that Workbench 6.2 (or close). [You have the release notes here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-utilities/en/index.html).